# mongo on nodejs collection not found

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I connect to a database and receive a client.
The next step is to create a collection (table).

```
db.createCollection("test", function(err, collection){    //I also tried db.collection(...
    if(collection!=null)
    {   
        collection.insert({"test":"value"}, function(error, model){console.log(model)});
    }
    else if(err!=null)
        console.log(err);
});
```

Now I would have created a collection "test" as well as a document(row) "test" in it.

Next is to get the content of the collection:

```
db.test.find({});    //An empty query document ({}) selects all documents in the collection
```

Here I get the error: Cannot call "find" of undefined . So, what did I do wrong?

Edit: I connect to the database this way:

```
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server("localhost", 27017, {native_parser:true}));
mongoClient.open(function(err,mongoclient){
if(mongoclient!=null)
{
    var db = mongoclient.db("box_tests");
    startServer(db);
}
else if(err!=null)
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: error points to "db" not being bound to a database

Comment: The connection is made in the edit of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the mongo command line you can use `db.test.find({})` but in javascript there is no way to replicate that interface so far (maybe with harmonies proxies some day).

So it throws an error **Cannot call "find" of undefined** because there is no **test** in db.

The api for the node.js driver of mongodb is like this:

```
db.collection('test').find({}).toArray(function (err, docs) {
  //you have all the docs here.
});
```

Another complete example:

```
//this how you get a reference to the collection object:
var testColl = db.collection('test');

testColl.insert({ foo: 'bar' }, function (err, inserted) {
  //the document is inserted at this point.

  //Let's try to query
  testColl.find({}).toArray(function (err, docs) {
    //you have all the docs in the collection at this point
  }); 
});
```

Also remember that mongodb is schema-less and you don't need to create the collections ahead of time. There are few specific cases like creating a capped collection and few others.

Comment: I couldn't find that in the mongo-api. database.collection.find() is used a lot there.

Comment: The mongo nodejs driver documentation has two problems: 1-really bad SEO. 2-It looks exactly the same than the mongo doc. You can look here http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html

Comment: +1 for point on being schemaless and no need to create up front.

Answer (score 1):

If you call db.test.find "next" after the db.createCollection block it ends up being immediately next before db.createCollection succeeds.  So at that point, db.test is undefined.

Remember that node is async.

To get the results I believe you are expecting, db.test.find would have to be in the collection.insert callback where you're calling console.log(model).

```
db.createCollection("test", function(err, collection){   
    if(collection!=null)
    {   

        // only at this point does db.test exist

        collection.insert({"test":"value"}, function(error, model){
            console.log(model)

            // collection and inserted data available here
        });
    }
    else if(err!=null)
        console.log(err);
});

// code here executes immediately after you call createCollection but before it finishes
```

Checkout the node async.js module.  Good writeup here: http://www.sebastianseilund.com/nodejs-async-in-practice

Comment: It doesn't exist in the callback either